# avg. disk write queue length performance counter for individual disk in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract the disk realted perf counters. Below is the query that I am using now.

```
get-counter -counter '\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length'| select -ExpandProperty countersamples
```

The above returns an expected result for each physical disk separately as shown below.

[image: Result returned by the above query on a stand alone server]

However, when we execute the same query on a cluster based env, the drive details cannot be obtained individually.

[image: Resultset obtained in a cluster based env]

I need to extract the perf counter values for the disk individually on clustered env as well.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue or limitation.  [A cluster is a shared disk name as far as normal operations are concerned and will be seen as one drive, not individual drives](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27perf%20counter%20for%20clustered%20drive%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27perf%20counter%20for%20clustered%20drive%27&sc=4-34&sk=&cvid=5511363483124AC09FEBE99C7314F0AB). If you want that individual drive info, you can't do that on a shared clustered drive. Clusters technically mean all perf expectations are identical in order to support direct failover, and operational state.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I was able to get the desired result by using logicaldisk perf counter.

Comment: No worries, glad to know it helped and got you over to the logical drive side of this. Most folks often overlook/forget the difference when calling physical vs logical resources.